# Using jQuery on dynamically loaded element

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook, dynamic

I am using the following code to retrieve the number of likes from the Facebook Graph API, and this works perfectly. What I am having trouble doing is using jQuery .css to alter the color of the last character in the returned value.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(function() {
        //Set Url of JSON data from the facebook graph api. make sure callback is set   with a '?' to overcome the cross domain problems with JSON
        var url = "https://graph.facebook.com/krewella?callback=?";

        //Use jQuery getJSON method to fetch the data from the url and then create our unordered list with the relevant data.
        $.getJSON(url,function(json){
            var html = "<ul><li>" + json.likes + "</li><li>" + json.about + "</li></ul>";
            //A little animation once fetched
            $('.facebookfeed').animate({opacity:0}, 500, function(){
                $('.facebookfeed').html(html);
            });
            $('.facebookfeed').animate({opacity:1}, 500);
        });
      });
    </script>

</head>

<body>
    <div id="wrapper"><!--wrapper open-->
        <div class="facebookfeed">
        <h2>Loading...</h2>
    </div>
    </div><!--wrapper closed-->
</body>
```

Comment: can you add the structure of returned value here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about something like:

```
json.likes = json.likes.toString().slice(0,-2) + "<span class='red'>" + json.likes.toString().substr(-1) + "</span>"
var html = "<ul><li>" + json.likes + "</li><li>" + json.about + "</li></ul>";
```

With the trivial css:

```
.red{
    color:#ff0000;
}
```

Comment: Asad - I get an Uncaught TypeError: Object 106270 has no method 'substr'

Comment: @JasonHalsey Isn't `json.likes` a string?

Comment: @JasonHalsey Try logging it to your console and see what it is.

Comment: if I add json.likes = '' + json.likes; the json will load but the span doesnt show up

Comment: @JasonHalsey From the docs it looks like it's a number. Try the updated code.

Comment: The updated code worked perfectly. Thank you so much. I have been banging my head against the desk all day trying to figure this out.